# How to control positioning of the KendoUI dropdown and prevent its overlapping of the input text box?

Tags: css, combobox, kendo-ui

I've been seeing one strange thing which I can't solve and it is related to the fact that in my site the drop down portion of the combo box and/or drop down list overlaps/hides the text entry. Is there anyone who faced the same issue and if yes how it was solved ?

**<UPDATE>**

Link of the repro page showing the overlapping can be found here [kendotest.azurewebsites.com](http://kendotest.azurewebsites.net/) 
**</UPDATE>**

Illustration of the problem in 3 pictures...

Here's how it looks on a KendoUI demo web site - **proper behavior**
[image: Proper behavior - from kendo ui web demo site]

And here's the behavior on my site -  **faulty overlapping**
[image: Combo box in collapsed state]
[image: My Combo in expanded state]

Comment: Can you share a sample page - this is not an expected behavior and screenshot is not enough for a diagnose?

Comment: Guys, I can't reproduce your problem without a sample page.

Comment: @Bundyo, sorry for late response - I've made a dummy page reproducing the *defect* here: http://kendotest.azurewebsites.com.

To reproduce it just start typing name of one of the items ie. "X-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer

Default MVC 4 template has in site.css next entry for body:

```
body
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

enter code here
```

When I remove the **border-top** line the dropdown starts working as it should

Comment: Yes, seems the issue is caused by the completely different document.body metrics in the various browsers - we chose not to support margins and borders of the body at all or face unpredictable behavior.